# c# SendMessage Left Mouse Click With ANSI

Tags: c#

How can I use SendMessage with ANSI?

```
private const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
private const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
private const uint MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001;

SendMessage(hwndMain, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, new IntPtr(MK_LBUTTON), CreateLParam(pt.X, pt.Y));
SendMessage(hwndMain, WM_LBUTTONUP, new IntPtr(MK_LBUTTON), CreateLParam(pt.X, pt.Y));
```

It works but I'm wanting to send message by ANSI

User32.dll function that can use!

[image: User32.dll #1]
[image: User32.dll #2]

Comment: What do you mean "with ANSI"?

Comment: Unicode and ANSI names:
SendMessageW (Unicode) and SendMessageA (ANSI)

[See More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

i dont understand with SendMessageW vs SendMessageA